# Trying to check if information written in a text file is equal to a variable within shell script

Tags: bash, variables, equals

I'm still a newbie to Linux scripting. My goal is to determine if the information written in a .txt file is equal to a variable within the script. This is the code that I have written so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=-5

if [$(cat < top.txt) -eq $a ]; then
    echo "YES!"
else
    echo "NNOOO!"
fi
```

Please let me know what I should be doing. To reiterate, I want top.txt to equal `-5`. I currently have `-5` written in the text but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: `[` is not mere syntax, it's a command. Therefore it requires a space after it to separate it from it's arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use More Quotes™:](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

```
[ "$(cat top.txt)" = "$a" ]
```

However, beware that this doesn't handle the case where `top.txt` ends with a newline - `$()` will chop that right off. So you might be better served with this:

```
[ "$(cat top.txt; printf x)" = "$a"x ]
```

Another issue is that you can't check files containing the NUL character this way; variables *can not* contain NUL characters.

At this point I'd be tempted to ask [what you are trying to achieve.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[ "$(<top.txt)" -eq "$a" ] && echo "YES!" || echo "NOOOS!"
```

Comment: Right but question tag was `BASH`

Comment: and the shebang is /bin/sh

Comment: And on many systems it's dash or some other more POSIX-y shell. As I said, it's an assumption that the OP will need to clarify.